# octoberCMS | extra actions during creation into plugin created on "Builder"

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins, october-form-controller

Imagine that I have a Plugin `Gallery` that was made on `Builder`, and after creation of `Slide` I want to do some extra actions...

Imagine that I want to create another `Slide` with some changes to another plugin... (After redirect to `/update/:id`)

So as I understand I need to extend a `Constructor`?

I need something like adding an extra class to a `<body>`...

Here's an example:

```
public function update($id) {
    $this->bodyClass = 'compact-container';
    return $this->asExtension('FormController')->update($id);
}
```

this function is called before the generation of a page, and I need something similar after creation of a "Slide"

Comment: And what is your question? Sry, its not that clear...

Comment: @dragontree well, for now I have an answer :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have analyzed file `modules/backend/behaviors/FormController.php` and I found these functions, that can help me to do some extra actions after and before creating things on some plugins:

```
/**
 * Called before the creation or updating form is saved.
 * @param Model
 */
public function formBeforeSave($model)
{
}

/**
 * Called after the creation or updating form is saved.
 * @param Model
 */
public function formAfterSave($model)
{
}
```

All I need to do, is put those function into my controller's file